# I need a timer that disable submit button

Tags: forms, timer

I need to create a timer for my website. I am setting up a form with multiple choice questions. i want users to submit the form/ answers at a specified time say 30 minutes,.. if the time elapses the submit button get disabled and alert message; time is up, Test failed. 
Help with entire code; Jquery, and PHP Pease;

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you haven't shown what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use the `setTimeOut()` javascript function.

The following line for example shows an alert box with the text Hello, after 3 seconds.

```
 setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
```

In your case you want to disable a submit button and show an alert after **30 minutes**, 30 minutes = 30*60 = 1800 seconds, equals 1800000 miliseconds.

So the code becomes like this:

```
 setTimeout(function(){ 
     //disable the button with id="submitbutton"
     document.getElementById('submitbutton').disabled = true;
     alert("Time out!"); 
  }, 1800000);
```

To make this work once the page is loaded you need to place it in a javascript file or `<script></script>` tags and wrap it in the on document ready event. The complete code is then:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
Your HTML here with the <input type="submit" id="submitbutton">

<script>
// self executing function
(function() {
     setTimeout(function(){ 
         //disable the button with id="submitbutton"
         document.getElementById('submitbutton').disabled = true;
         alert("Time out!"); 
      }, 1800000);

})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```